# Two apparently identical .png files display at different resolutions on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimage, photoshop, screen-resolution

I have a .png file that I am using for a UIButton

```
[bookmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It looks fine, but I'd like to be able to change its appearance in Photoshop.

As a test, I open the .png in Photoshop, then save it as a "Bookmark copy.png" without making any other changes or edits.

Then I change the code to:

```
[bookmarkButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark copy.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Now when I run the app on the iPhone the same icon appears at a lower resolution.

When I examine the two different .pngs both appear to have the same resolution and appear identical in other applications.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening??

Thanks!

Comment: what if you copy the file with your file system, not photoshop, to remove that as a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save it for 3 different device resolution. like 1x-2x and 3x.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

you can find information from this link.